# Convert file from Adobe Illustrator to TikZ

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, latex

For those of you who know how LaTex is used to digitally typeset, TikZ is similarly used to draw.

I can not find a way in Adobe Illustrator to convert an image to any format in `TikZ` and `PGF`.

`TikZ` is built on top of PGF and allows you to intuitively and easily create sophisticated graphics, as well as portable graphics in PDF/PostScript formats using plain (pdf)TEX, (pdf)Latex, or ConTEXt.

Sources [here](https://www.tcs.uni-luebeck.de/en/mitarbeiter/tantau/forschung/software/) and [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ).

**I have two questions**:

1. With Inkscape this conversion is possible; but how should I proceed with Adobe Illustrator?
2. Is there an online tool that allows you to convert images of any format or in .pdf format into a .tex (LaTeX) file?

Comment: perhaps you'd have better luck asking this at [tex.se]

Comment: I'm a moderate LaTeX user: you can see my reputation on the site you brought back to me. I write you what I know. I would be curious if by concatenating several tools online with Adobe Illustrator it is possible to realize what I have asked. Thank you for +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export to SVG from Illustrator. SVGs are also the native format of Inkscape, which in turn can export to TikZ in several ways (as you already noted and elaborated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370876/28608).

Sure, this is somewhat tedious, but you can likely automate large parts of the process (I didn’t test it).

Comment: I have used Inkscape to generate directly code in TikZ, but it takes a lot of time. I've never done the test of the content because my laptop has a graphics card with a very low ram and I can not install two vector graphics programs. Here is the reason for requesting online tools. Thank you for your answer that I vote positively but I thought that with the new version of AI 2018 could achieve what I wanted. I always positively vote any answer because the user dedicates precious time to me. I already had a positive vote. My greetings.